# ¿Cómo serializar los checkbox no seleccionados en jQuery y/o Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero enviar por POST todos los valores de mi formulario usando `serialize` o `serializeArray`, incluyendo los `checkbox` que no estén seleccionados, pero descubro que estos dos métodos **ignoran los `checkbox` que no estén seleccionados**.

¿Hay alguna manera **no demasiado forzosa** de forzar la serialización de todos los checkboxes, incluyendo los no seleccionados?

```js
$(
  function() {
    $("#frmPersonas").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      var dataSerializeArray = form.serializeArray();
      var dataSerialize = form.serialize();
      console.log(dataSerialize);
      console.log(dataSerializeArray);
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Formulario simple que enviará una petición POST -->
<form id="frmPersonas" action="" method="post">
  <label for="POST-name">Nombre  :</label>
  <input id="POST-name" type="text" name="name" value="Prueba" /><br /> Uno:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkUno" id="chkUno" checked /> <br /> Dos:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkDos" id="chkDos" /> <br />
  <hr />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: mira lo que encontre en este [ejecutable](http://jsfiddle.net/GVZ8S/256/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En jQuery podrías usar los que no estén seleccionados haciendo esto:

```
$("#frmPersonas input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)")
```

o también así:

```
$("#frmPersonas input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked")
```

Cualquiera de esos dos métodos va a devolver una lista con los inputs que no hayan sido marcados. Una vez obtenidos, añadirlos a tus datos serializados requeriría sólo recorrer dicha lista (con un `each` por ejemplo) y concatenar o insertar dependiendo de si es una cadena o un array:

```js
$(
  function() {
    $("#frmPersonas").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      var dataSerializeArray = form.serializeArray();
      var dataSerialize = form.serialize();
      
      $("#frmPersonas input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").each(function() {
        dataSerializeArray.push({ "name": this.name, "value": "off" });
        dataSerialize += (dataSerialize.length > 0 ? "&" : "") + this.name + "=off";
      });
      
      console.log(dataSerialize);
      console.log(dataSerializeArray);
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Formulario simple que enviará una petición POST -->
<form id="frmPersonas" action="" method="post">
  <label for="POST-name">Nombre  :</label>
  <input id="POST-name" type="text" name="name" value="Prueba" /><br /> Uno:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkUno" id="chkUno" checked /> <br /> Dos:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkDos" id="chkDos" /> <br />
  <hr />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Álvaro me gusta tu respuesta. Pero ¿podrías explicar que sentido tiene el uso del operador ternario en el caso de  `dataSerialize`?

Comment: @A.Cedano Estaba intentando hacer una respuesta genérica que sirviera para cualquier formulario (si no se ha marcado ningún campo, la cadena estará vacía y tener un & podría dar error). Aunque en este caso no importa porque hay un campo de texto que siempre se serializará.

Answer (score 3):

no he usado serialize ya que no se muy bien que hace, pero espero que te sirva.

```js
$(
  function() {
$("#frmPersonas").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  var dataSerializeArray = form.serializeArray();
  var dataSerialize = form.serialize();

$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(indice, inputDatos){
 if ($(inputDatos).is(":checked") === false){
   var objeto = new Object();
 objeto.name = inputDatos.id;
 objeto.value = "off"
 dataSerializeArray.push(objeto);
 }
  
})
  
  console.log(dataSerializeArray);
});
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmPersonas" action="" method="post">
  <label for="POST-name">Nombre  :</label>
  <input id="POST-name" type="text" name="name" value="Prueba" /><br /> Uno:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkUno" id="chkUno" checked /> <br /> Dos:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkDos" id="chkDos" /> <br />
  <hr />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Interesante propuesta pero, dado que los chequeados ya los serializa, y tampoco quiero renunciar a `serialize`
 ¿no sería mejor aliviar el código, buscando los no chequeados solamente y añadirlos a la variable creada ya con `serialize`?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que solo se añada los check que no han sido marcados. Espero que te sirva

Comment: Buena respuesta. Como comentario, deberías hacer el selector de los `input` más concreto. Tal y como está ahora, se podrían seleccionar incluso `input` que están fuera del formulario. Poniendo un `$(this).find(...)` o simplemente el id del formulario al principio del selector evitará resultados inesperados.

Comment: Si estas en lo cierto que tendría que añadir quien es padre para que solo tenga en cuenta los que están dentro. Tu respuesta es mejor engloba todo y evita el if que añadi. Siempre se aprende algo nuevo